# How to enable the (JAR) file to access an external folder that is needed in the application?

Tags: java, file-io, jar

Please, My Java application is suppose to access an external folder which contains some other files. It was working perfectly under the Netbeans IDE but not when i run the (jar) file alone. I thought including the external desired folder within the same path as the jar file will solve the issue but sadly it gave me the same results.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

P.S: I am using the following command: java -jar MyJarFile.jar

[Added]

**My File structure:**

In the main folder of the project i have the following:

**build

build.xml

Data: Inside this folder is my log file (log.dat).

dist: Inside this folder is my (.Jar) file.

manifest.mf

nbproject

README

src**

The code to access the file is written as follows:

**File logs_File = new File("Data" + File.separator + "log.dat");**

Again within my NB it is working this way but not when i lunch the .Jar file.

**[Updated]**

Up to know, i have been trying the following:

The file to access the file looks as follows now: 
File logs_File = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/Data/log.dat").toString());

Then i copied the Data folder to following directories:
**src

build/classes/

dist**
**and in the main directory**

And still it is not seeing the file. Though this time not even netbeans is able to locate the file.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: including the external folder within the same path... - that doesn't really make much sense. first up - what's the exact error you're facing? is there an exception, or is the external folder inaccessible? or...?

Comment: The external folder is inaccessible or not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is as follows:

I printed the `getAbsolutePath();` of my file then i placed my (Data) folder inside the (dist) folder with the (JAR) file. I had also to allow the (jar) file to be accessible by all users and not just the administrative one.

**[Topic Solved]**

Thanks for the community and all your help and concern!

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's hard for someone to give you a precise answer to your question.  The hint that you provided about correct behavior within the IDE suggests to me that you may be using a relative path when accessing your file?  Have you tried to print out the path you're attempting to access when it fails?

EDIT:

Try calling `getAbsolutePath()` on your file, and printing the results to STDOUT.  Then go look in your file system to see if the file exists.

Comment: Yes i used a relative path as follows:
"log" + file.seperator + file.dat
Where the log folder is located in the same folder as the project. 
The Jar file is in a different folder though.

Comment: Is the jar file in the folder directly above log?  If not, thats your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your notes! The ("log") folder is directly in the above directory of my JAR file. Including it with my JAR file or in the same folder is not getting any results. (as discussed above)

Comment: The Jar file needs to be above the log, not the other way around.

Comment: Well i copied the file all over the place and still is not seeing it. it is suppose to read from Data/log.dat where this file is located in the main directory of the project. within the same directory as the (dist) itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need folllwing structure and code for your project
[image]

Comment: Thanks! but i didn't quite understand. I shall edit the build.xml, then i shall change what in the properties? besides, i shall replace (file.reference.quartz-1.5.2.jar) with the name of my jar file and the (build.classes.dir) with my classes' directory? Please if you rephrase your explanation i would be very grateful.

Comment: if the scenario implies to yours then edit build.xml you just need to read project.properties file and take all the external jar's pointers from there and make such entry in build.xml as mentioned above

Comment: Well actually the application is running only from NB. Even when the JAR is in the (dist) folder, it is still not able to find to the desired external file. [File not found]

Comment: can you run that jar from command line  java -jar jarName.jar , and post the output

Comment: well simply after running the above command the program is printing my custom message which says: "Error: File not found!". This message is programmed to be in the output if the file is not found. Would you like me to add anything to my source file in respect to this?

Comment: yes the source which is trying to access file and whole exception stacktrace instead just a message

Comment: well after printing             System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
I got the following: Data/log.dat (No such file or directory)

Comment: can you please post a bit of the code where it is trying to access file along with your dir structure where your file is and your source .

Comment: For sure... Please take a look at my update in my original post above. Thanks :)

Comment: put data folder under source and then `File logs_File = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/data/log.dat"));` then clean and build and it will work :)

Comment: File logs_File = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/data/log.dat")); is reporting an error in (new File). The word "File" in new file in underlined. This is may be because of the constructor. There must have been a syntax error in the above line.

Comment: `File logs_File = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/data/log.dat").toString());`  I don't have compiler at this moment , check thisadd `toString()` it will work :)

Comment: Sadly, it is reporting (file not found) now. I copied the (Data) folder inside the source and outside but still the same result. Only this time though it is not working from the NB either :(

Comment: I hope you have data folder in side `src` and so `src/data/data.log` and the above code , please confirm this

Comment: i have copied the Data folder to everywhere. I mean, it must be really blind for it not to see it now. We are doing something wrong it seems in the above line. I have no idea. [by the way, thanks a lot for spending the time to help... really appreciated!]

Comment: it should work , one more time can you please edit your project structure and code in question properly, it must work, and data dir is need to be inside src only, can you also post the jar's strucrure which is getting build in dist by opening it in any Archieving utils

Comment: snapshot will do if you aren't confortable with texting structure

Comment: check my update, I tried locally its working :), note: I am using win machine for now so here dir are case insensetive so `Data` will work for me , I would suggest you to use `data` in the code

Comment: Thanks I see... From where I am calling there is no main class. The class where am operating in doesn't contain any main. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: ok then suppose your class name is Foo then reaplace `Main.class` with `Foo.class`

Comment: It is not working for me at all! I am sorry for all the trouble. :( 
I making a mistake somewhere... Thanks a lot though for everything.

Comment: The only way remain is post such screenshot :) so that I can take a look at it tomorrow and make it working , it should try checking error message and try to find out the things till then off to sleeeeeeep.

Comment: Till then try following step to findout the issue, try printing out whole stacktrace , try printing out the filepath as I did in screen shot is it the same or what  ? I am sure you will make it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish if i can send it to you by mail or something and hopefully we get the chance to introduce each other as well ;D | Good Night!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jigar Joshi! I solved it! It was merely a simple task but had just some bad luck yesterday ;D